# How to tell a script to stop when a execution of script that it calls ends with specific condition

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have a `master.sh`script that calls 2 other scripts

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/script1
/home/script2
```

script1 has a following condition:

```
if [ $len -lt 10 ]; then                       
echo "mask is not 10"                                    
exit                                               
fi
```

How to i tell master.sh not to proceed to script2 if script one makes that exit condition? In other words, stop executing subsequent scripts if $len is not 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard way is to exit with a non zero exit status on error:

```
if (( len < 10 )) ; then
    echo Mask is not at least 10. >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

You can then simply check the exit code:

```
/home/script1 && /home/script2
```

If there are several things that can go wrong and you want to react to a failure, you can exit with various exit codes and examine them in the parent with $?:

```
/home/script1
case $? in 
    0) /home/script2 ;;
    1) echo 'Fatal problem' ;;
    2) echo 'Missing file' ;;
    # etc.
esac
```

For the non-standard situation, I'd capture the output:

```
[[ $(/home/script1) == 'mask is not 10' ]] && exit
/home/script2
```

Comment: Might make sense to suggest specific error codes too in case that's useful (to differentiate failures).